# Google Places API show schools and stores

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, maps

Using the Google Maps API with the places library I am able to show nearby schools using the recommended method shown [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search).

```
var map;
var infowindow;

function initMap() {
  var pyrmont = {lat: -33.867, lng: 151.195};

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch({
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 500,
    type: ['store']
  }, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

The problem is that if I also want to show nearby stores as well as schools, everyone seems to recommend simply doing this:

```
type: ['store', 'school']
```

While this technically works, the problem is the map just shows a bunch of meaningless default markers with no way of knowing what it what.

So my question is: How can I change the icon for the schools and stores? Ideally I would show a different icon for each different type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no different than adding custom marker in regular map.Only thing is that you need to make api calls separately for each `type`.So even `type: ['store', 'school']` would work and you get results but there is no type specifier in the `results` to tell whether it's a school or shop .Also you would need to create their separate callbacks for setting their separate icons

```
  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      icon:"http://example.com/icon.png", //<-- only this line is enough for icon
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });
```

go through [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sanddune/spxqrox8/) for a better understanding

Moreover every result will have a default icon (as `icon` property), that can also be used

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      icon:place.icon,
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
});
```